# Ejecutar proyecto PHP en VSCOde

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, netbeans, apache, vscode

Estoy con la duda de que si con Visual Studio Code puedo ejecutar un proyecto PHP (con conexion a una base de datos remota) de igual forma como lo hago con NetBeans. Ya he intentado usando Apache, osea accediendo desde localhost/nombreproyecto/login.php pero no pasa del login poniendo bien el user y contraseña. En el caso de NetBeans solo apreto F6 y se ejecuta el proyecto perfectamente pasando el login. Quisiera saber como serian los pasos para hacer lo mismo pero con VSCode. Ya he intentado con Live Server y nada, no ejecuta el PHP o algo me estara faltando.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de manera muy simple, instalando la extension PHP Server y iniciando proyecto ya funciona todo de diez.